# Generate possible sequences CSV values from a row

Tags: csv

I'm trying to build synonyms database and getting stuck at this step.

For example:

I have CSV values - Ant,Cat,Dog. And I do need to generate possible sequences from that CVS row.

Ant,Cat,Dog
Cat,Ant,Dog
Dog,Ant,Cat

Would it be possible to achieve such results by using Notepad++ or Excel?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/104420/how-to-generate-all-permutations-of-a-list-in-python

Comment: Python is easy :)

Comment: Thanks @arahant ... but I'm no good at Python. Seems like need to learn Python.